# Xcode hangs on "linking" only on release mode

Tags: c++, ios, iphone, xcode

I am building a C++ project created with JUCE for iPhone, using Xcode 6.4.

For some reason it hangs on the linking stage when trying to run on a device. The device is a jailbroken iPhone 3 running iOS 7.1. Debug builds run fine on the device but I need to test with release builds (debug builds run very slow).

I am using Ad Hoc code signing.

I followed the tutorial here: https://angelxwind.net/?page/how2asu

Comment: Maybe it has to do with the old hardware or rather old iOS version. Try using an older Xcode version, maybe that helps.

Comment: You might be right. It does finally link and install on the device it just takes a long time to complete. I am running an old 2009 Macbook Pro (Core2Duo) so I guess it could be all the link-time optimisations that Xcode does for release builds.